# Ordinal Regression - Using a Continuous Attribute of 3 Categories as a Covariate as a Proxy for the Categories

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, research-design

I'm conducting an ordinal regression with SPSS 28. I have 3 subsets in my data (n=87 total, mostly equally distributed between the subsets) that represent 3 different scenarios where study participants were given an excerpt of text to read. I split the scenarios into 3 dummy variables and included them as factors, but I realized that what I'm *really* interested in is differences in responses as part of the Flesch-Kincaid grade level of the text.

Originally, I ran the regression with the three dummy variables as factors (along with another factor), but I found the resulting regression model to not have as strong of a relationship as I expected. I then ran the model with the Flesch-Kincaid grade level of each of the 3 scenarios (set as a new continuous variable) as a covariate and received stronger results that met passed on the model fitting, goodness-of-fit, and parallel lines tests and also had significant relationships between the additional factor and the covariate.

### Considerations/thought process

- Using the Flesch-Kincaid grade levels will make the model more usable and generalizable outside of my study.
- The study intended to find a relationship between readability and the dependent variable.
- The Flesch-Kincaid grade levels of the excerpts are not equally spaced apart, i.e., 8, 10, 16. By including this as the covariate instead of the dummy variables as factors, I should be able to weigh the difficulty of the text as a factor of the model instead of just A, B, or C.

### Concerns

- I only have 3 unique values for Flesch-Kincaid grade levels. This feels like the predictive power might be reduced?
- I'm essentially using a continuous variable as a proxy for the nominal variable. It feels odd, so I want to really get a second opinion on this.

I would like to know if it's appropriate to **use an attribute of the subsets (the Flesch-Kincaid grade levels) in an ordinal regression as a proxy for the subsets** or if I might be getting *too creative* and running the risk of overfitting/breaking some rules I don't know about.

Comment: It would be really helpful to provide plots of your data and summary of the results you've got so far. For example: There are 87 observations and you can plots the outcome against the Flesch-Kincaid grade levels coloring points by the other factor. Did participants read one or several excerpts?